# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.remove : Is it safe to use

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

i am trying to schedule bunch of tasks to execute periodically. under certain situations some task need to be stopped from scheduling, so i remove them from the interal queue of threadPoolExecutor. I do that from within the task itself

Below is my approach. I am not sure the idea of removing the task from the threadPoolExecutor service, from inside of the task can cause any problem.(look at the synchronized method name 'removeTask'. Is there a better way to accomplish what i am trying to do here.

```
public class SchedulerDaemon  {


    private ScheduledExecutorService taskScheduler;
    private ScheduledFuture taskResult1, taskResult2;
    private Task1 task1;
    private Task2 task2;


    public SchedulerDaemon(Task1 task, Task2 task2)
    {
        this.task1 = task1;
        this.task2 = task2;1
        taskScheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    }


    public void start() {
       if(taskScheduler == null) {
           taskScheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
           taskResult = taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TaskWrapper(task1) , 60000,60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
           taskResult2 = taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TaskWrapper(task2) , 60000,60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

       }
    }


    public void stop() {
        if(taskScheduler != null) {
            taskScheduler.shutdown();
            taskResult1.cancel(false); 
            taskResult2.cancel(false);           
            taskScheduler = null;
            taskResult = null;
        }

    }

        public  synchronized void removeTask( TaskWrapper task){
            ((ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) taskScheduler).remove(task);
        }

    class TaskWrapper implements Runnable {
        private Task myTask;

        public TaskWrapper(Task task) {
            myTask = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
               boolean keepRunningTask = myTask.call();
               if(!keepRunningTask) {

                   ***//Should this cause any problem??***
                   removeTask(this);
               }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //the task threw an exception remove it from execution queue
                ***//Should this cause any problem??***
                removeTask(this);
            }
        }



    }
}


public Task1 implements Callable<Boolean> {

public Boolean call() {  
if(<something>)
return true;
else
return false;    
}
}



public Task2 implements Callable<Boolean> {

    public Boolean call() {  
    if(<something>)
    return true;
    else
    return false;    
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you schedule a task

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = schedulerService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AnyTask());
```

Future Object is returned.
  Use this Future Object to cancel this Task.
  try this

```
  future.cancel(true);
```

from JavaDocs

```
  /**
     * Attempts to cancel execution of this task.  This attempt will
     * fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled,
     * or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful,
     * and this task has not started when <tt>cancel</tt> is called,
     * this task should never run.  If the task has already started,
     * then the <tt>mayInterruptIfRunning</tt> parameter determines
     * whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in
     * an attempt to stop the task.
     *
     * <p>After this method returns, subsequent calls to {@link #isDone} will
     * always return <tt>true</tt>.  Subsequent calls to {@link #isCancelled}
     * will always return <tt>true</tt> if this method returned <tt>true</tt>.
     *
     * @param mayInterruptIfRunning <tt>true</tt> if the thread executing this
     * task should be interrupted; otherwise, in-progress tasks are allowed
     * to complete
     * @return <tt>false</tt> if the task could not be cancelled,
     * typically because it has already completed normally;
     * <tt>true</tt> otherwise
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

Canceling a task by force is dangerous, that is why stop is mark to remove from java, so,
in alternative you should have a shared flag in your thread...

something like: can i live? can i live? no? ok return! this seam hugely but is the safe way!

Comment: i am not cancelling the task, i am removing it from the internal queue of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor , i am not sure what you mean by having a shared flag and how would that address what i am trying to do, can you please put some code examples